# Choosing a default browser in Windows 10 does nothing

Tags: windows-10, default-settings

When I click "Choose a default" in Settings and then pick a browser nothing happens.

I've even tried editing the Registry directly and setting the values there, and windows still defaults to Edge.

I even have a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YbYxU5Waz0I

This registry key is already set, to zero effect:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Associations\UrlAssociations\https\UserChoice]
"ProgId"="ChromeHTML"
```

Comment: You didn't watch the video...

Comment: The video shows me trying what is suggested in the link and it not working.

Comment: The video you refuse to watch shows your suggestion not working...

Comment: Watch it again. It didn't reset anything, it didn't do ANYTHING.

Comment: I'd already reset and that was the whole problem. Your suggestion doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: You never specified that.